# move the origin of an image to bring it back to the center in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

I am working on Windows Forms Applications, i have loaded an image into a pictureBox. I want to know if it's possible to move origin of image and bring it back to the center.

I have this : [image1](https://i.goopics.net/EabRV.png)
I want this : [image2](https://i.goopics.net/lRljx.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could snap an area of the image and display this instead. This could look as follows:

```
var nX = bmpOriginalImage.Width / 2;
var nY = bmpOriginalImage.Height / 2;
var nWidth = bmpOriginalImage.Width - nX;
var nHeight = bmpOriginalImage.Height - nY;

var rect = new Rectangle(nX, nY, nWidth, nHeight);

var bmpSnapImage = bmpOriginalImage.Clone(rect, bmpOriginalImage.PixelFormat);

m_pbxPictureBox.Image = bmpSnapImage;
```